# How to run Spark application assembled with Spark 2.1 on cluster with Spark 1.6?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, sbt-assembly

I've been told that I could build a Spark application with one version of Spark and, as long as I use `sbt assembly` to build that, than I can run it with spark-submit on any spark cluster.

So, I've build my simple application with Spark 2.1.1. You can see my build.sbt file below. Than I'm starting this on my cluster with:

```
cd spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/    
spark-submit --class  App --master local[*] /home/oracle/spark_test/db-synchronizer.jar
```

So as you see I'm executing it with spark 1.6.0.

and I'm getting error:

```
17/06/08 06:59:20 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getTimeAsMs(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)J
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD.<init>(KafkaRDD.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:284)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$2.apply(JobGenerator.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$2.apply(JobGenerator.scala:241)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$start$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(JobGenerator.scala:86)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
17/06/08 06:59:20 WARN AkkaUtils: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(<driver>,[Lscala.Tuple2;@ac5b61d,BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 26012))] in 1 attempts
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1309342978]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:427)
17/06/08 06:59:23 WARN AkkaUtils: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(<driver>,[Lscala.Tuple2;@ac5b61d,BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 26012))] in 2 attempts
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1309342978]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:427)
17/06/08 06:59:26 WARN AkkaUtils: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(<driver>,[Lscala.Tuple2;@ac5b61d,BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 26012))] in 3 attempts
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1309342978]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:427)
17/06/08 06:59:29 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(<driver>,[Lscala.Tuple2;@ac5b61d,BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 26012))]
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:209)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:427)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1309342978]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:194)
        ... 1 more
17/06/08 06:59:39 WARN AkkaUtils: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(<driver>,[Lscala.Tuple2;@5e4d0345,BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 26012))] in 1 attempts
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1309342978]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:427)
17/06/08 06:59:42 WARN AkkaUtils: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(<driver>,[Lscala.Tuple2;@5e4d0345,BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 26012))] in 2 attempts
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1309342978]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:427)
17/06/08 06:59:45 WARN AkkaUtils: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(<driver>,[Lscala.Tuple2;@5e4d0345,BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 26012))] in 3 attempts
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1309342978]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:427)
17/06/08 06:59:48 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(<driver>,[Lscala.Tuple2;@5e4d0345,BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 26012))]
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:209)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:427)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1309342978]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.askWithReply(AkkaUtils.scala:194)
        ... 1 more
```

Base on some reading I see that typically error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is connected to different versions of Spark. And that might be true because I'm useing different ones. But shouldn't `sbt assembly` cover that? please see below by build.sbt and assembly.sbt files

**build.sbt**

```
name := "spark-db-synchronizator"

//Versions
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
val sparkVersion = "2.1.1"
val sl4jVersion = "1.7.10"
val log4jVersion = "1.2.17"
val scalaTestVersion = "2.2.6"
val scalaLoggingVersion = "3.5.0"
val sparkTestingBaseVersion = "1.6.1_0.3.3"
val jodaTimeVersion = "2.9.6"
val jodaConvertVersion = "1.8.1"
val jsonAssertVersion = "1.2.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % sl4jVersion,
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % sl4jVersion exclude("log4j", "log4j"),
  "log4j" % "log4j" % log4jVersion % "provided",
  "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % jodaConvertVersion,
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % jodaTimeVersion,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestVersion % "test",
  "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % sparkTestingBaseVersion % "test",
  "org.skyscreamer" % "jsonassert" % jsonAssertVersion % "test"
)

assemblyJarName in assembly := "db-synchronizer.jar"

run in Compile := Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in(Compile, run), runner in(Compile, run))
runMain in Compile := Defaults.runMainTask(fullClasspath in Compile, runner in(Compile, run))

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

// Spark does not support parallel tests and requires JVM fork
parallelExecution in Test := false

fork in Test := true
javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
```

**assembly.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

Comment: Thanks @eliasah. Time for some clean up...and remove the comments :) Sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct and it **is** possible to run a Spark application with Spark 2.1.1 libraries bundled on **some** Spark 1.6 environments like Hadoop YARN (in CDH or HDP).

---

The trick is fairly often used in large corporations where the infrastructure team forces development teams to use some older Spark versions only because CDH (YARN) or HDP (YARN) do not support them.

---

You should use `spark-submit` from the newer Spark installation (I'd suggest using the latest and greatest 2.1.1 as of this writing) and bundle **all** Spark jars as part of your Spark application.

Just `sbt assembly` your Spark application with Spark 2.1.1 (as you specified in `build.sbt`) and `spark-submit` the uberjar using the very same version of Spark 2.1.1 to older Spark environments.

As a matter of fact, Hadoop YARN does not make Spark any better than any other application library or framework. It's quite reluctant to pay special attention to Spark.

That however requires a cluster environment (and just checked it won't work with Spark Standalone 1.6 when your Spark application uses Spark 2.1.1).

In your case, when you started your Spark application using `local[*]` master URL, it was **not** supposed to work.

```
cd spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/    
spark-submit --class  App --master local[*] /home/oracle/spark_test/db-synchronizer.jar
```

There are two reasons for this:

1. `local[*]` is fairly constrained by CLASSPATH and trying to convince Spark 1.6.0 to run Spark 2.1.1 on the same JVM might take you fairly long time (if possible at all)
2. You use older version to run more current 2.1.1. The opposite *could* work.

Use Hadoop YARN as...well...it does not pay attention to Spark and has been tested few times in my projects already.

---

> I was wandering how can I know which version of i.e.spark-core is taken in runtime

Use web UI and you should see the version in your top-left corner.

[image]

You should also consult web UI's **Environment** tab where you find the configuration of the runtime environment. That's the most authoritative source about the hosting environment of your Spark application.

[image]

Near the bottom you should see the **Classpath Entries** which should give you the CLASSPATH with jars, files and classes.

[image]

Use it to find any CLASSPATH-related issues.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this works only because YARN doesn't use Spark "binaries", right?

Comment: do you know any way how can I check what binaries are used when executing spark-submit? I've just start same jar with:
spark-submit --class  net.atos.dbsynchronizator.App --master yarn --deploy-mode client /home/oracle/spark_test/db-synchronizer.jar
and got same error:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getTimeAsMs(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)

Comment: the name we see is such because: assemblyJarName in assembly := "db-synchronizer.jar" in build.sbt. Jar has aprox 140MB so I assume this is accually fat jar.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski yes thanks! A lot of knowledge here :) However I'm still struggling to understand why my app builded with Spark 2.1.1 is actually started with version of spark related to spark-submit script I'm using. I've put `println(ssc.sparkContext.version.toString)` inside app and when I use spark-submit from 1.6.0 version then it prints 1.6.0. When I use spark-submit from 1.3.0 than it prints 1.3.0. I've tested that with master: `local[*]`, `spark://...` and `yarn`. Always the same result- never recived 2.1.1. Maybe I have some untypical settings there...

Comment: I think I may have misinformed you. You can `spark-submit` from Spark 2.1.1 and deploy to envs with Spark 1.6 libs? That's why it works for YARN and Mesos where libs are external and only to help cut the uberjar's size. So, submit your Spark app to YARN using Spark 2.1.1's `spark-submit`. Latest version can talk to older not the opposite.

Comment: Reworded the answer to make it GREAT again :) Sorry for misinforming you.